# error reading string resource in java file

Tags: java, android, string

Error:(90, 20) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
How to fix the error

in lineR.string.Invalid_city_name

using the method

getstring(R. string.Invalid_city_name)
the same error what is wrong?

```
            status="success";
        }else{
            status=R.string.Invalid_city_name;
        }
```

full Code:

```
package com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.ActivityMain;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.adapter.ItemLocationAdapter;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.data.Constant;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.data.DatabaseManager;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.data.GlobalVariable;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.model.City;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.R;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.model.ForecastResponse;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.model.ItemLocation;
import com.nbdev.app.weatherapp.model.WeatherResponse;

public class JSONLoader extends AsyncTask<String, String, ItemLocation>{
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private String jsonWeather = null, 
            jsonForecast= null, 
            status="null";

    private Context ctx;
    private LinearLayout lyt_form;
    private LinearLayout lyt_progress;
    private TextView tv_message; 
    private Dialog dialog;
    private DatabaseManager db;
    private GlobalVariable global;
    private ActivityMain act;

    public JSONLoader(ActivityMain act, LinearLayout lyt_form, LinearLayout lyt_progress, TextView tv_message, Dialog dialog) {
        this.act=act;
        this.ctx=act.getApplicationContext();
        this.lyt_form=lyt_form;
        this.lyt_progress=lyt_progress;
        this.tv_message=tv_message;
        this.dialog=dialog;
        global  = (GlobalVariable) act.getApplication();
        db = new DatabaseManager(act);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        lyt_form.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lyt_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ItemLocation doInBackground(String... params) {
        ItemLocation itemLocation   = new ItemLocation();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            City city = db.getWordsFormAutocomplate(params[0]);
            if(city!=null){
                itemLocation.setId(city.getId());
                itemLocation.setName(city.getName());
                itemLocation.setCode(city.getCode());

                String url_weather      = Constant.getURLweather(city.getId());
                String url_forecast     = Constant.getURLforecast(city.getId());

                JSONObject json_weather     = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_weather,"POST", param);
                JSONObject json_forecast    = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_forecast,"POST", param);

                jsonWeather     = json_weather.toString();
                jsonForecast    = json_forecast.toString();

                itemLocation.setJsonWeather(jsonWeather);
                itemLocation.setJsonForecast(jsonForecast);

                status="success";
            }else{
                status=(R.string.Invalid_city_name();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemLocation;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ItemLocation result) {
        lyt_form.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lyt_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(status.equals("success")){
            global.saveLocation(result);
            act.refreshList();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        tv_message.setText(status);
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    };

}
```

Comment: change this "status=R.string.Invalid_city_name;" to this
"status=act.getString(R.string.Invalid_city_name);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a context/Activity to get string from your resources.

change this:

`status=R.string.Invalid_city_name;`

to this

`status=act.getString(R.string.Invalid_city_name)`;

Comment: thank you very much, it worked

Comment: Welcome.. just make sure to select this answer as solution to indicate this question is answered. @NikolaiBuzovskiy